# using jquery to highlight either tr's or td's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables:

```
<table class="highlight_row" id="table1">
  <tr id="first_row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="first">first thing</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="second">second thing</td>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="third">third thing</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="highlight_td" id="table2">
  <tr id="second_row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="fourth">fourth thing</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="fifth">fifth thing</td>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="sixth">sixth thing</td>      
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I am trying to differenciate them -- when I check any box in the first table, I want that whole row to be highlighted, and when I check a box in the second table, I want just that td to be highlighted.

I am able to get rows highlighted (using addClass() to a 'selected' color), but when I specify the table class, I still get the whole row for the second table, when I just want the td (I figure identifying by class instead of id will be better in the long run as I add more tables).

jquery code:

```
$(".highlight_row").click(function(){
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected", this.checked)
  })
});
```

Comment: Post your jQuery -- I feel like you may be selecting all `td` elements for your first example.

Comment: you can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by definition. Post code that isn't working so people can help you figure out why. You gain by learning more that way and we don't have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Can we see your jquery event calls? As user above me says could be grabbing wrong element

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/126qx6y7/), perhaps?

Your HTML.

CSS:

```
.highlight { background: #ff0; }
```

JS:

```
$("#table1 input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function ()
{
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('highlight');
});

$("#table2 input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function ()
{
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first table, you'll want to eval all of the checkboxes so it doesn't get un-highlighted. The second table is much easier.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24vm61dk/

```
$(function () {
    // Highlight Row
    $('#table1 input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
        var anyChecked = false;
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                anyChecked = true;
            }
        });
        if (anyChecked) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });

    // Highlight Cell
    $('#table2 input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        if (checked) {
            $(this).closest('td').addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('td').removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code shown is adding change handler within a click handler on the whole table.

This will lead to compounding events and can lead to serious browser performance problems if user clicks a lot in table.

Simply put, click on table 4 times and every time a checkbox gets changed it will trigger 4 change handlers

A simple way for the row highlighting would be to use the count of checked checkboxes in the row to determine the class state

```
$('table.highlight_row input:checkbox').change(function(){
      var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
          hasChecked = $row.find(':checkbox:checked').length;

      $row.toggleClass('selected', hasChecked);          
});
```

The cell highlighting is even easier...just toggle the class on the parent cell based on the checked state

```
$('table.highlight_td input:checkbox').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

For rows use:

```
.highlight_row .selected {
    background: yellow;
}
```

for the cell use:

```
.highlight_td .selected td:nth-child(1) {
    background: yellow;
}
```